# How to not change owner and group when editing file in Sublime Text?

Tags: files, sublime-text, ownership

I have file with owner `www-data` and group `www-data`. When I modified this file, it automatically change file owner to current user `victor` and group `victor`.

Can I modified foreign file without owner and group changes?

NOTE: Manually change file owner and group after edit does not fit

NOTE: I use **Sublime Text 3** text editor for editing files

Comment: I updated my answer with a better solution, perhaps you want to check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add yourself permanently to the `www-data` group:

```
adduser <username> www-data
```

<sub>`<username>` = your username</sub>

Or, alternatively, use `sudo` to temporarily launch `subl` as a member of the `www-data` group:

```
sudo -g www-data subl <file_path>
```

<sub>`<file_path>` = your file's path</sub>